# PYTHON Library: как использовать RecoverPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, library

Я нашел эту библиотеку:

https://github.com/PabloLec/RecoverPy#Tips

1. Я установил библиотеку: **`python3 -m pip install recoverpy`**
2. Я пытался запустить эту команду с помощью CMD: **`python3 -m recoverpy`**

Но это не работает. Кто-нибудь может мне помочь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А когда библиотеку устанавливали вы как питон запускали? Тут же проблема, что система не видит питон.

Comment: используйте `py -m recoverpy` или `python -m recoverpy`. Если не получается покажите что `pip freeze` выводит

Comment: обе ваши команды приводят к этой ошибке: **`ImportError: cannot import name 'geteuid' from 'os' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\os.py)`**

Comment: Очень интересно. На скриншоте у вас система вообще не может питон найти, а тут получается находит, но версия питона видимо не совместима с recoverpy

Comment: Я считаю, что на скриншоте была неправильная команда. @Dmitry имеет право.

Comment: Под windows запускайте просто через python, не python3.

Comment: @insolor как я могу это сделать?

Comment: В вашем вопросе везде где в командах упоминается python3 - писать просто python. Но это поможет только при условии если у вас Python вообще установлен)

Comment: Я уже установил Python, конечно @insolor